# metasploit - dllinject vs Reflective injection

Tags: code-injection, metasploit

I have a question regarding dllinject payload in metasploit.
What is the difference of the injection method between dllinject payload and meterpreter payload?
Does the technique the same? (Reflective-Dll loading?)
Because I didn't see reflective-dll in memory when I used dllinject payload...

Somebody knows?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "meterpreter" is just a special payload among all the other payloads . (It can be categorised into reverse_tcp and blind_tcp of course) . On the other hand , the dllinject payload yields the same result but it exploits the victim in a different manner by linking a file to a malacious DLL file .

I would recommend meterpreter payload because the dllinject payload does not get triggered until the victim opens the file .

But both of them ultimately give you the same result by using different techniques .